# Spark sc parallelize specify number of partitions

Tags: apache-spark

I want to download a list of files in Spark and do some processing on it. The downloads are big and the memory footprint is around ~40GB. So, I want each executor to download one file, flatten it and operate on it. Is there a way that I can do it with sc.parallelize? My current approach is:

```
val list = List("fileToDownload1", "fileToDownload2", ...)
sc.parallelize(list, list.length)
  .map(file => downloadFile(file))
  .flatMap(fileContents => fileContents)
  .map(row => someOperation(row))
```

but it splits the list such that each executor ends up having multiple paths to download. I think that's because list.length is interpreted to be for each task within the executor. As a temporary workaround, I'm setting spark.executor.cores to 1 so that each executor gets one file. But, it ends up slowing down the someOperation(row) part.

So, what I want is for sc.parallelize to split so that each executor gets one element in the list. Is there a way to do that in Spark?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just put your files on HDFS so that every executor can access them ?

Comment: I think the best you can achieve is to choose a large number of partitions in sc.parallelize. This way chances are good the each partition contains exactly 0 or 1 filename